# how to hide bottom zero from page in slide part

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to make slider in ionic framework.I am able to make slide user able to swipe left and right and different page display .But On page there is **zeros display** on bottom of page .I need to hide that zero .user swipe left and write without display zeros on bottom

could you please tell me how to hide that zeros

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOErVd

```
<ion-slide-box active-slide="myActiveSlide">
  <ion-slide>
    <div class="box blue"><h1>BLUE</h1></div>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <div class="box yellow"><h1>YELLOW</h1></div>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <div class="box pink"><h1>PINK</h1></div>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use jQuery or css for this. You can hide the pager directly on the `ion-slide-box`:

```
<ion-slide-box active-slide="myActiveSlide" show-pager="false">
```

See the [ionSlideBox docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/).

Answer (score 1):

It could be some grammar mistakes on your part, but I assume you mean the three round page-indicators. add this css to hide them.

```
.slider-pager{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by **jQuery** as

```
$(".slider-pager").hide();
```

Or by **CSS** as

```
.slider-pager{display:none}
```